# I cannot install APC

Tags: installation, php5, pecl, alternative-php-cache

I have php 5.3.6 and ubuntu. I want to install APC.

When I do the `$ pecl install apc`, I eventually get an error:

```
In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:44:0:
/usr/include/php5/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: fatal error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [apc.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

When I try to do `$ yum install php-pecl-apc` I always get error: `No package "php-pecl-apc" available`

I tried doing a `$ yum clean all`, but it did not make a difference.

I am not sure how to proceed. What do you suggest?

Comment: Ubuntu and Yum?  That's... unusual.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`yum install pcre-devel` . You need the Perl-compatible regular expression library development header files

You mention Ubuntu, might as well use `apt-get install libpcre3-dev`

Comment: I just get `yum install pcre-devel
There are no enabled repos.
 Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
 You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>
` when I try this.